# Prevent table tr clickable-row when click in button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like some help in my code:

I need the click in tr, but when click in the button i need open a modal... I don't need the modal code, my only question is how I can prevent the function when click the button?

Bellow my code work fine...

```js
  $(".datagrid").delegate('tbody tr', 'click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
          
          console.log('OK.. I need this click in TR');
          console.log('But, how to prevent if click comes the button???');
          
          });
```

```css
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #c5dffa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-hover dataTable datagrid" cellspacing="0">
  <thead >
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>BLABLA</th>
      <th>BLEBLE</th>
      <th>BLIBLI</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="clickable-row">
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" >
        button
      </button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>blablablablabla</td>
    <td>blebleblebleble</td>
    <td>bliblibliblibli</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `e.target.tagName`:

```js
$(".datagrid").delegate('tbody tr', 'click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    console.log('The button was clicked');
  } else {
    console.log('The TR was clicked (not the button)');
  }

});
```

```css
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
.table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #c5dffa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-hover dataTable datagrid" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>BLABLA</th>
      <th>BLEBLE</th>
      <th>BLIBLI</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
            button
          </button>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>blablablablabla</td>
      <td>blebleblebleble</td>
      <td>bliblibliblibli</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```